# clang++ auto return type error for specialization of templated method in templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, clang++, auto

Trying to understand [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054055/clang-fails-to-compile-template-function-with-auto-return-type-inside-a-template), I've simplified the example obtaining the following code.

```
template <bool>
struct foo
 {
   template <typename T>
      auto bar (int i)
       { return i; }
 };

template <>
template <typename T>
   auto foo<true>::bar (int i)
    { return i; }

int main()
 {
   return 0;
 }
```

g++ 4.9.2 compile it without problem; clang++ 3.5 give the following error

```
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:12:20: error: out-of-line definition of 'bar' does not
      match any declaration in 'foo<true>'
   auto foo<true>::bar (int i)
                   ^~~
```

Substituting one of the two `auto` returning values with `int`, there are no changes: g++ compile and clang++ give the error. Substituting both `auto` with `int`, the error disappear.

The `template <typename T>` part is significant because the following code compile without problem with both compilers

```
template <bool>
struct foo
 {
      auto bar (int i)
       { return i; }
 };

template <>
   auto foo<true>::bar (int i)
    { return i; }

int main()
 {
   return 0;
 }
```

My question is obvious: who's right?

g++ or clang++?

I suppose that g++ is right and that this is a bug from clang++ but I ask for confirmation.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Try gcc 6.1 and clang 3.8 ..

Comment: This was a Clang issue. It works with 3.8: https://godbolt.org/g/JkCJ6l

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054055/clang-fails-to-compile-template-function-in-a-template-class-specialization-whi).
Except you also should take into account that implicit auto return type is allowed only since C++14, so you should either use `-std=c++14` compilation flag, or explicitly set the return type (for C++11).

The problem is that CLang does not match well specialization of the template functions of the template class. To overcome this you should have an empty declaration of the template class and separate specializations:

```
template <bool>
struct foo;

template <>
struct foo <false>
{
   template <typename T>
   auto bar (int i)
   { return i; }
};


template <>
struct foo <true>
{
   template <typename T>
   auto bar (int i)
   { return i; }
};

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but your link to "Solution" is the same link to the "another question" that I cite in my question. And the accepted "solution" is my answer to that question. And, obviously, where talking about C++14, non C++11, how tagged (there is no C++11 tag). My question isn't "how to solve?" but "who's right?". You're saying (if I understand correctly) "g++ is right and clang++ is wrong". But I was hoping in an answer that cite the relevant part of the official standard. (sorry again for my bad English).

Comment: Hi @max66, sorry that I didn't recognize you at once, you was the guy who first provided the solution.
For me there is no question "who is right": the standard allows template declaration that is also the definition and it allows templates specialization. So, obviously CLang just lacks making template function definition of the template class specializetion in the case when the template class declaration is also it's definition. It's not a CLand bug, just not implemented feature yet, because CLang is young and CLang 3.8.1 compatible to GCC 4.2.1 (which is a pretty old version).