# Is this partial class specialization buggy or is it a bug in clang or gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, partial-specialization

```
template <class A>
struct Foo {
  template <class Bar>
  constexpr auto a_method();
};

template <class A>
template <class Bar>
constexpr auto Foo<A>::a_method() {
    return 42;
}

template <>
template <class Bar>
constexpr auto Foo<void>::a_method() {
    return 42;
}
```

GCC [can](https://godbolt.org/z/s5Koxo6x9) compile this.

But Clang [cannot](https://godbolt.org/z/9rKa5sv7M). The errors output:

```
<source>:15:27: error: conflicting types for 'a_method'
constexpr auto Foo<void>::a_method() {
                          ^
<source>:4:18: note: previous declaration is here
  constexpr auto a_method();
                 ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Clang complains also without the unspecialized definition.

Comment: Looks like a Clang bug, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061994

Comment: Look like it fixes the problem when adding `-> int` for return type. I can't explain why clang fails though.

Comment: If you first provide the class specialiaztion: `template <>
struct Foo<void> {
  template <class Bar>
  constexpr auto a_method();
};`, it [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Wzh9ece3f) with clang.

Comment: If I see that code I am not sure if it is not ill formed. The signature of a template declaration contains the return type which is here `auto` which is equivalent to an unnamed template parameter. If we now define the template later with a deduced return type `int` the signature is different as `int` is a fixed type and not longer a template parameter. In this case, clang will be ok to not accept it. If we only define the `int` type but not `Bar` in the given case, it is a partial specialization which should also not compile.

Comment: I've reported the bug to clang: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53139

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a **problem** only when  the keyword `auto` is used as the return type of the function in your above code.

For example, if you don't use `auto` as the **return type** of the function `a_method` and instead use any other type as the return type then the program will [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/f3YMbaY9b).

This seems to be a bug in Clang.

Another thing i have noticed is that if you first provide an **explicit specialization** for the class template, then the code will [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/E183anWM7) with `auto` .